# Using tensorflow in ML, why my kernel restarts constantly?

Tags: python, tensorflow

from the kernel :

```
In[1]: runfile('/home/yannick/Documents/ML/MNIST-reco/neural_network_V1.py', wdir='/home/yannick/Documents/ML/MNIST-reco')

Restarting kernel...    

In [1]:
```

The thing is that when i run the code, instead of working, it restarts the kernel and nothing happends
please help me

```
import tensorflow as tf
import input_data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

img = mnist.train.images[0]
img = img.reshape((28,28))
plt.imshow(img, cmap=cm.Greys)
plt.show()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
# ex : [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

W = tf.get_variable('weights', [784,10])
b = tf.get_vairable('bias', [10])
y = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,W), b)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y_,logits=y))

train_step = tf.trin.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variable_initializer())

def feed_dict(is_training):
    if is_training :
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    else:
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.test.images,mnist.test.labels
    return {x: batch_x, y_: batch_y}

for i in range(100):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict(True))
        print('étape %d: Précision du training:%f' % (i, acc))
    else :
        sess.run([train_step], feed_dict=feed_dict(True))
    
print('Précision Test: ', sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict=feed_dict(False)))
```

Comment: What is this? Please format your question properly.

Comment: Might be a resonance cascade for all we know. Please share the error message.

Comment: Sometimes Kernel stops when memory / cpu is full

Comment: here we go, i finally understood the editor of stackoverflow !

Comment: @BeamsAdept yes, i know that but now, i'm good, 63 %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to delete my tensorflow lib and reinstall it using anaconda, then it work again. It's just about re-importing the libs on anaconda and relaunch spyder.
hth